# ArchlinuxArm on Raspberry: Can't sync datetime at boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, ntp

I have a raspberry pi I use for an irrigation system. The problem is it doesn't have hardware clock so, every time it reboots, the system time is wrong, and I cannot set it to sync it automatically.

I have discover that when the system time is wrong, dns requests doesn't work, so every time I try to send a request I just get:

```
[root@alarmpi me]# ntpdate 3.es.pool.ntp.org
Error resolving 3.es.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
12 Aug 15:37:15 ntpdate[2385]: Can't find host 3.es.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
12 Aug 15:37:15 ntpdate[2385]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

By the way I get the same connection errors if I try to use pacman, wget, python/requests, even ping... So it is a dns thing for sure.

```
[me@alarmpi ~]$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

If I set the time and date manually, it works again, but I live 300km from where this thing is, and I can't do it manually every day there is a power cut.

```
[root@alarmpi me]# timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2019-08-12 15:47:40 CEST
           Universal time: Mon 2019-08-12 13:47:40 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
[root@alarmpi me]# timedatectl set-ntp false
[root@alarmpi me]# timedatectl set-time "2019-08.13 10:45:45 CEST"
[root@alarmpi me]# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.168.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.168.174 (172.217.168.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.168.174 (172.217.168.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=31.6 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 292ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.739/27.161/31.583/4.422 ms

[root@alarmpi me]# ntpdate 3.es.pool.ntp.org
13 Aug 10:49:54 ntpdate[2498]: adjust time server 37.139.121.60 offset 0.004894 sec
```

So I'm a little lost here. How can I sync the clock automatically if it doesn't let me connect to the service because I'm out of sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some NTP servers listen directly on IP addresses and advertise themselves as such. For instance, [NIST](https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) provides IPs for each of their NTP servers, so you can pick one and do `ntpdate <IP>` on init. This won't need DNS resolution and should work right away.

Alternatively, you can also try to use the `fake-hwclock` package, which preserves the approximate time between reboots. It's not perfect and does not provide the accurate time, but it might be enough to resolve the domain names for NTP.